# Label, Panel,... BorderStyle in compact framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I want to make border for label and panel in Compact Framework 3.5 but there is no such property like BorderStyle. I search and google but i don't know how can i make border for label and Panel in compact framework.

Comment: you can create user control. Place panel with black background, and add on it label with white background, leaving small margins.

Comment: Just draw your own with Graphics.DrawRectangle in a Paint event handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

senzacionale, try to use the panel Paint event to draw your border. In this little example I painted a blue border around the panel:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue), 0, 0, 
                             e.ClipRectangle.Width-1, 
                             e.ClipRectangle.Height-1
                            );
}
```

This example was written in WinForms/.net 4.0/VS2010, but the principle is the same, and the Paint event is available in the Compact Framework. There are a few tricks to redraw things properly in the Paint event, like creating a copy of e.Graphics to work with, but the main idea is presented.